# TikZ – draw arrow with empty space in the middle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to know how I can draw an arrow/line with an empty space in the middle or `\dots` in the middle.
For example:

```
-----    ----->
```

Or:

```
---- ... ----->
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is my try after the first answer, but still could not get it do work:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%
% Choose how your presentation looks.
%
% For more themes, color themes and font themes, see:
% http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/index_by_theme.html
%
\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
    \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
    \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,automata,shapes}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.7,auto,swap,>=latex]
        \draw [thick] (0,0) --node {\dots} (12,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: What are the definition for the dots or the empty space? To they have a specific length? Is it a specific part of the line length? How about curved lines?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel interesting points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply add an empty (or not for the dots) node along a path/edge. The default position is `midway`, so you don't need to specify anything in particular. The width of the "gap" can be set by changing the minimum width of the node.

**Edit**: Since you use the beamer class, I changed the code slightly, but it's still Tikz. Get the new code from below.

Now your nodes along the paths are called `mynode`, so the style won't affect other nodes you might want to draw. Implementing what I said in the comments, you can manually specify the node position by entering `pos=<number>` where number is a decimal point from 0 (start) to 1 (end). `midway` (default) is `pos=.5`, for example.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta,automata,shapes}

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
    \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
    \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    xscale=0.7,
    auto,
    swap,
    ->,
    >=latex,
    mynode/.style={rectangle,fill=white,anchor=center}]

        \draw[thick] (0,3) --node[mynode,minimum width=2cm] {} (12,3);
        \draw[thick] (0,2) --node[mynode,minimum width=1cm] {} (12,2);
        \draw[thick] (0,1) --node[mynode,pos=.7] {$\dots$} (12,1);
        \draw[thick] (0,0) --node[mynode,pos=.2] {$\dots$} (12,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion, but could not get it to work. See my edit in the post, please.

Comment: @MJS I'm looking into it.

Comment: @MJS See edited answer.

Comment: What If I wanted the dots at say, 3/4 of length?

Comment: @MJS You can mark a position along a path by using numbers from 0 to 1. So 3/4 would be 0.7 I think. Try writing `... node[mynode, pos=.7] ...` and tell me if it works.

Comment: I would like there to be dots midway and 3/4 do distance. I tried adding another node but I think I may be getting the syntax wrong

Comment: @MJS That's a different question and you should ask a new one, but I don't know of a way off the top of my head.

Comment: Maybe add `sloped` for non horizontal arrows

Answer (score 2):

Another approach you might find more (or less) intuitive.

The pos value will place the dots (or text or whatever) at that proportion of the line length (0.5 in middle)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta,automata,shapes}

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
    \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
    \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\coordinate (S) at (-4,0);
\coordinate (E) at ( 4,0);
\draw[->] (S) -- (E) node[pos=0.7,fill=white] {...};
\end{tikzpicture}

    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is no different from the answer above (see the comments under the answer).

Comment: Indeed I said that. For someone without experience of Tikz the layout of the code might be a little more intuitive. That's all.

Comment: Actually you said "another approach", which is not. And I don't understand what layout you're referring to.